# C# Testing for null

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm using C# to write a simple program to read Active Directory and display the value held in a AD field on a Windows form program.

If a property doesn't exist then the program crashes, below is my code, how can I catch this and move on to the next field without doing a try/catch for each and every attribute?

```
DirectoryEntry usr = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, username, password);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(usr);
searcher.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + GlobalClass.strUserName + ")";
searcher.CacheResults = false;
searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");

//program crashes here if telephoneNumber attribute doesn't exist.
textBoxFirstName.Text = usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just checking `usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"]` will not work. You must check the actual value. The reason the error is occuring is because you're calling `ToString()` on `Value` which is null.

`user.Properties` will always return a `PropertyValueCollection`, regardless of the property name entered into the collections indexer.

I.e.

```
var pony = usr.Properties["OMG_PONIES"]; // Will return a PropertyValueCollection
var value = pony.Value;                  // Will return null and not error
```

You need to check the value itself, the best way through the null coalescing operator:

```
textBoxFirstName.Text = (usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value 
                            ?? "Not found").ToString();
```

Comment: But won't that fail if `usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"]` is `null`?

Comment: @Jim Mischel - No. It's never null. Look at my `usr.Properties["OMG_PONIES"]` example. I thought the same as the rest of the answers until I tested it myself. You can sit typing `Properties["RAR_FOO_DOH"]` and it'll never return null.

Comment: +1, I didn't think to check if usr.Properties[] would actually return null.

Comment: Ahhh, I see.  It returns an empty collection if the property doesn't exist.  I need to wake up.  You said that explicitly in your response.

Comment: If ***not exists*** `telephoneNumber`, how-to add it (properties) with **null value** ?

Answer (score 3):

Store the contents of `usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"];` in a variable and check for `null`:

```
PropertyValueCollection tel = usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"];

textBoxFirstName.Text = (tel != null && tel.Value != null)
                      ? tel.Value.ToString()
                      : "";
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer of the bunch, because it doesn't index Properties twice, I have no idea how cheap that is though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the null-coalescing operator (??) operator.

```
textBoxFirstName.Text = (usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value 
                            ?? String.Empty).ToString();
```

This way the value is replaced with an empty string if null. You could also just return `null` instead of `String.Empty`, the reason your code is crashing is because you're trying to call `ToString()` on a `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. If telephoneNumber is not null, it will convert the value to a string, otherwise it will use an empty string.

```
textBoxFirstName.Text = usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value != null 
        ? usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString()
        : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things will help this be more graceful:

- Test usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"] for null before calling child properties like Value. I haven't worked with AD myself, but most string-keyed indexers are designed to gracefully handle non-existent keys. the CLR, on the other hand, will happily throw a NullReferenceException any time you try to reference a member of anything that evaluates to null.
- On the off chance that AD DOES blow up on a nonexistent column, enclose the assignment in a Try-Catch block that will show an error on the screen and gracefully continue processing (or not).

Comment: @Sander: if usr.Properties[] is throwing it (unlikely but possible), there's not much else he can do, unless the dictionary provides a safe method to check for column existence like a ContainsColumn() method.

Comment: ah I see what you mean, but I'm quite sure it doesn't behave like that, and that .Value is what causes the null ref.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
SearchResult.Properties.Contains("property")
```

To check if the object actually has the prop loaded from the search result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"] != null)
    textBoxFirstName.Text = usr.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();
```